# Create and Filter EC2 with Tags

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

Trying to create a Lambda function in AWS using Python 3.6, which creates an EC2 instance that gets terminated after a specific period of time. Since I am still very green with this, I chose to use 'Tags' to be used as a filter when terminating the instances.

However, I am having trouble figuring out a way to add the tag to the instance as its being generated.

My code for creating the EC2 is as follows

```py
import os
import boto3

AMI = os.environ['AMI']
INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ['INSTANCE_TYPE']
KEY_NAME = os.environ['KEY_NAME']
SUBNET_ID = os.environ['SUBNET_ID']

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    instance = ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName=KEY_NAME,
        SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1
    )

    print("New instance created...")
```

The environment variables are filled out manually

I also have a termination function, where it is supposed to filter out the EC2's created by the python script above with a Tag and terminate them

```py
import os
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    instances = ec2.instance.filter(Filters=[{"Name" :"tag:webserver", "Values":[delete] }])
    deleteInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]
    for i in deleteInstances:
        terminateInstances = ec2.instances.terminate(i)
        print(terminateInstances)

    print("Terminating instances...")
```

Having no luck on finding methods to do this simply.

Comment: You didn't tag the new instance when you created it

Comment: earlier up top I said I was not sure how to tag them on creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add an additional parameter to your request, for example:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId=AMI,
    InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
    KeyName=KEY_NAME,
    SubnetId=SUBNET_ID,
    MaxCount=1,
    MinCount=1,
    TagSpecifications=[
      {
        'ResourceType': 'instance',
        'Tags': [
            {
                'Key': 'TAG_KEY',
                'Value': 'TAG_VALUE'
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
)
```

Comment: i added this to my code and did a little test and it encountered an error 
"You are not authorized to perform this operation" 
"Client error"

I checked the IAM role and it has 
```json
{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```
I am not to sure whats the issue

Comment: I think you can add permission '"ec2:CreateTags"' to your IAM role

Comment: I added that also and gave it all resources, however when i tried it, same error 

Would i need to make a new function or should the role be auto-updated

Comment: Try to use `"ec2:*"` for test

Answer (score 0):

boto3 create_instances api have parameter **TagInstances**.
 [documentation here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_tags)

TagSpecifications is a python list - It includes tags to apply to the resources during launch.The specified tags are applied to all instances or volumes that are created during launch.

```
TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'instance',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
```